# How can I use a very large dictionary in C#?

Tags: c#, memory

I want to use a lookup map or dictionary in a C# application, but it is expected to store 1-2 GB of data.

Can someone please tell if I will still be able to use dictionary class, or if I need to use some other class?

EDIT : We have an existing application which uses oracle database to query or lookup object details. It is however too slow, since the same objects are getting repeatedly queried. I was feeling that it might be ideal to use a lookup map for this scenario, to improve the response time. However I am worried if size will make it a problem

Comment: Have you tried spinning up an instance of a dictionary that uses that much memory?  Also, is this application to be deployed on 32 or 64 bit system?

Comment: Why a dictionary or in-memory data structure?  Why not a database?

Comment: SqlLite has a cool in-memory db that might be interesting for your situation.

Comment: If you calculate on 2gb and you control the server itself, just shoot. No server are feel better using "3gb of free 16 available" then 14 of ree  16. Memory are not works that way, nothing is more fast to use for r/w access then RAM. If the memory load IS a problem, the other comments here, are more worth!

Comment: i have heard of external memory stl containers for C++, but am not aware of c#. is there a similar alternative in c#?

Comment: You should optimize your database.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Short Answer**

Yes.  If your machine has enough memory for the structure (and the overhead of the rest of the program and system including operating system).

**Long Answer**

Are you sure you want to?  Without knowing more about your application, it's difficult to know what to suggest.

- Where is the data coming from?  A file?  Files?  A database? Services?
- Is this a caching mechanism?  If so, can you expire items out of the cache once they haven't been accessed for a while?  This way, you don't have to hold everything in memory all the time.
- As others have suggested, if you're just trying to store lots of data, can you just use a database?  That way you don't have to have all of the information in memory at once.  With indexing, most databases are excellent at performing fast retrieves.  You could combine this approach with a cache.
- Is the data that will be in memory read only, or will it have to be persisted back to some storage when something changes?
- Scalability - do you expect that the amount of data that will be stored in this dictionary will increase as time goes on?  If so, you're going to run into a point where it's very expensive to buy machines that can handle this amount of data.  You might want to look a distributed caching system if this is the case (AppFrabric comes to mind) so you can scale out horizontally (more machines) instead of vertically (one really big expensive point of failure).

**UPDATE**

In light of the poster's edit, it sounds like caching would go a long way here.  There are many ways to do this:

- Simple dictionary caching - just cache stuff as its requested.
- [Memcache](http://sourceforge.net/projects/memcacheddotnet/)
- [Caching Application Block](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff647280.aspx) I'm not a huge fan of this implementation, but others have had success.

Answer (score 1):

As long as you're on a 64GB machine, yes you should be able to use that large of a dictionary. However if you have THAT much data, a database may be more appropriate (cassandra is really nothing but a gigantic dictionary, and there's always MySQL).

Comment: Just a side note... the application needs to be compiled to 64bit (or any cpu on 64bit machine) for the process to take up more than 2GB of memory (I think it's 2GB anyway).

Answer (score 1):

When you say 1-2GB of data, I assume that you mean the items are complex objects that cumulatively contain 1-2GB.

Unless they're structs (and they shouldn't be), the dictionary doesn't care how big the items are.
As long as you have less than about 2<sup>24</sup> items (I pulled that number out of a hat), you can store as much as you can fit in memory.

However, as everyone else has suggested, you should probably use a database instead.
You may want to use an in-memory database such as SQL CE.

Answer (score 0):

You can but For a Dictionary as large as that you are better off using   a DataBase

Answer (score 0):

Use a database.
Make sure you've a good DB model, put correct indexes, and off you go.

Answer (score -2):

You can use `subdictionaries`.

```
Dictionary<KeyA, Dictionary<KeyB ....
```

Where `KeyA` is some common part of `KeyB`.

For example, if you have a `String` dictionary you can use the First letter as `KeyA`.

Comment: How does this address the question? This looks like an obscure cache partitioning scheme and has nothing to do with answering whether the user should cache results from a database.

Comment: It solves a problem,  yes it is partitioning scheme (problem with dictionaries - memory allocation, when memory ends it allocates twice more memory, and using partition scheme can make the process not so painfull), and seems it is the only way you you want to have really big dictionary in the RAM (no in database), ofcourse if you have many RAM, or you will get OUT OF MEMORY. Also you can try to switch your application to 64-bits - maybe it should be first what you should try...