# Saving and Loading Dictionary. Improving Memory Footprint

Tags: c#, serialization, deserialization

Long time watcher and this is my first post so please go easy on me. I've looked around but my query is quite specific and I can't find it elsewhere.

I have an application which consists of 2 controls.

- A control on the left contains a tree view which displays searches mapped from an XML file. Each Search has an associated GUID.
- A control on the right displays a datagrid, the information of which I obtain from the tree view through a Dictionary (Guid<->Dataset).

When the user clicks on a node in the tree view, my application works out which GUID the search is linked with and presents the associated dataset which gets flattened and displays on the datagrid.

I save(Serialise) and load(Deserialise) the Dictionary when exiting/loading the application respectively.

I did some memory profiling recently and for larger searches the memory footprint of the Dictionary can be quite large (200mb) for the limited capacity of the user machines which I really need to sort out.

I was wondering if anyone had any idea how to achieve this.

I was thinking about splitting the Serialisable Dictionary into constituent Datasets and storing each one individually on the hard drive (maybe with the GUID as the filename). The saved Datasets would then be deserialised with each Node.Click event and displayed in the grid view. My worry about this is the potential pause in between each click event as it saves the old search and loads a new one.

Comment: What code do you want to see Enigmativity? There is quite a bit up there covering different aspects of the application.

Comment: Just the code that illustrates what's going on in your question. If we can see the essence of your code we might be able to provide better help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple answer, toss the dictionary and the datasets into a Sqlite file.  (or other db)  It will be a little slower but I expect faster than any code you can hand code in a reasonable amount of time.  If used correctly a db layer will do memory buffering and caching to make the ui more responsive.

Comment: Even better for .NET, use SQL Server Compact. But FYI, you can find out about large dictionaries here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5517320/how-can-i-use-a-very-large-dictionary-in-c

Comment: The reasons why I used Dataset was to allow the extraction of a snapshot of the database for them to have a presentation of the data at that current point in time. I could get around this by using timestamps in the database I suppose

The other fly in the ointment is that user can import columns into the Dataset from an external source. This could be 1+ How would I get around this when updating/inserting to the database on exiting the application?

Comment: Sorry, answering my own question. Worked out how to use user defined columns. Thank you so much for your answers. This resource has been totally invaluable to me. I'll use a database as a resource and construct the parameters of the search at run time.